# Nested selects not excluding data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, nested

I'm building this select statement, and got to a point where my conditions are not working. Here is the code:

```
select * 
from (
select ref,usr1,design,forref,replace(stock,'.',',')as stock 
from st
where inactivo like '0' 
and usr1 not in ('Serv','Reciclagem','portes','pbl','ctb','') 
and forref not in ('','0')
     ) total
where ref not in ('10159%','13159%')
order by usr1
```

The thing is, when I write the line to exclude certain values on ref table, nothing happens.

```
where ref not in ('10159%','13159%')
```

Where is it wrong?

Comment: Is the `%` supposed to be a wildcard? if so, then you need `not like` with 2 separate conditions with an `AND` between.

Comment: perfect, thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
WHERE LEFT(ref, 5) NOT IN ('10159','13159')
```

HTH!

Thanks.